# ajax and onbeforeunload

Tags: jquery, ajax, onbeforeunload

I want to inform my server that a user has closed browser tab/window with our app.

I found out that running an ajax call with `async:false` binded to a `window.beforeunload` evet will work and it does. Sort of...

```
window.onbeforeunload = beforeunload;

function beforeunload() 
{ 
    setSendingPowerStatus(false, true);

}
```

So, in *chrome* user closes the window and `setSendingPowerStatus(false, true);` function which in its implementation makes a synchronous call is being executed and when done browser closes the tab. In FF, on the other hand, user is prompted with that alert dialog asking *"Are U sure you wanna leave the page?"*.

My question is how to execute ajax call on *onbeforeunload* event without showing any dialog??? I mean I want to execute an ajax call before window is closed without bothering the user...

I also tried to *return false* also from my handler function, but without luck there either...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you retry like that(setting returnValue to true, and returning true) :

```
function beforeunload(event) 
{ 
    setSendingPowerStatus(false, true);
    event.returnValue=true;
    return true;
} 
window.onbeforeunload = beforeunload;
```